# lists of lists in prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I have a lists which contains 2 lists: the first one is a lists of lists and the second one the same. I want to make a list of lists which contains tuples with three elements. This is my initial list :

```
[ [ [1 2 3 4 a], [aa, bb], R1], [[ 1 3 4 5 b], [X, Y] , R2]] , [anything]]
```

I want to obtain this list:

```
[[a, [aa, bb], R1], [b, [x, y], R2]]
```

How can I implement a predicate to return me the list above in prolog? I have tried this :

```
get_game_tiles([[[_,_,_,_,I],[X,Y],R]|Tail], [[Elem1,Elem2|Tail]]) :-
   findall(S,
         (  member(S,[[[_,_,_,_,S], [X,Y], R], [[_,[_]]]]), S = I ),
         [[Elem1,_|_]]),
   findall([A,B],
         (  member([A,B] ,[[[_,_,_,_,S], [A,B], R], [[_,[_]]]]),
            A = X, B = Y
         ) ,
         [[_,Elem2|_]]),
   findall(Z,
         (  member(Z ,[[[_,_,_,_,S], [A,B], Z], [[_,[_]]]]),
            Z = R
         ),
         [[_,_|Tail]]).
```

Comment: Prolog doesn't have *functions*. It has *predicates*, which isn't the same thing. `[1 2 3 4 a]` and `[1 2 3 4 5 b]` are not a valid lists. Also, please show what you have tried and ask a more specific question.

Comment: Variables **must** start Uppercase

Comment: Still need some explanation for the rule to map the (still invalid!) list `[1 2 3 4 a]` to `a` and `[1 3 4 5 b]` to `b`. Are you simply just choosing the last element? What requires the treatment of `[aa, bb]` and `[X, Y]` to be different? What you're trying to do is a bit unclear. What happens when you try your solution (what results do you get)?

Comment: From the list [1, 2, 3, 4, a] I choose a. "a" is actually '#1' . Then I choose [aa, bb] which are actually two numbers and then I choose R. This is what I want to do for each list. My long list contains 2 lists: the first one has  lists, each other having  a list of 4 numbers, a list of two   numbers and a letter, and second list it doesn't matter at this point.  What I want to do is to make a list that contains a triplet with the last element from the list with 5 element, the list of 2 elements and the letter. I want to extract this 3 things from each list and to put the triplet into a list.

Comment: When I try my solution I receive "false"

Comment: But *why* do you choose `a` from `[1, 2, 3, 4, a]`? Is it simply you want the 5th element from the first list, the entire second list, and the entire 3rd item (variable)? And does the initial list have any number of elements of the form `[[_,_,_,_,X], [A,B], [R]]` followed then by `[anything]`? And encountering `[anything]` terminates the list? And `[anything]` doesn't match the other pattern?

Comment: I just have to put in a list of triplets those elements which I have written above. And I have 16 elements of the form  [[_,_,_,_,X], [A,B], [R]]

Comment: What is `[anything]`? Just anything that doesn't match, `[[,,,,X], [A,B], [R]]`?

Comment: Yes [anything] has a different form [ [M, N] | Tail] but I don't have to do something with it

Answer (score 2):

Your solution with `findall` calls is very over-done. There are some issues, such as the following:

```
member(S,[[[_,_,_,_,S], [X,Y], R], [[_,[_]]]])
```

and

```
member(Z ,[[[_,_,_,_,S], [A,B], Z], [[_,[_]]]])
```

These are a cyclic terms. You're querying whether `S` is a member of the list, `[[[_,_,_,_,S], [X,Y], R], [[_,[_]]]]`. `S` is embedded in a term within an element of the list you are asking if `S` is a member of. Likewise, you're asking if `Z` is a member of the list, `[[[_,_,_,_,S], [A,B], Z], [[_,[_]]]]`. `Z` is embedded in a term within an element of the list you are asking if `Z` is a member of.

```
member([A,B] ,[[[_,_,_,_,S], [A,B], R], [[_,[_]]]])
```

This isn't so much a problem but will always be false since the list consists of the following elements, neither of which match `[A,B]` (a list of two elements):

```
[[_,_,_,_,S], [A,B], R]  % a list of three elements
[[_, [_]]]               % a list of one element ([_, [_]])
```

Assuming I understand the conditions of your problem (I am not yet convinced 100% that I do), the approach in Prolog is actually much simpler:

```
get_game_tiles([], []).             % Empty list maps to empty list
get_game_tiles([S|_], []) :-        % List starting with non-matching pattern results in
    S \= [[_,_,_,_,_], [_,_], _]].  %   empty and ends recursion
get_game_tiles([[[_,_,_,_,X], [A,B], R]]|T], [[X, [A,B], R]|TR]) :-
    get_game_tiles(T, TR).
```